# "Brunnian" words in solvable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, free-groups

Let $G$ be a group, and call a word $W(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in letters $x_i$ and $x_i^{-1}$ "$G$-Brunnian" if there exist $g_1,\dots,g_n\in G$ with $W(g_1,\dots,g_n)\neq1$, but $W(h_1,\dots,h_n)=1$ as soon as one of the $h_i$ is trivial.

Variant: allow $W$ to also include constants from $G$.

Example: in any non-nilpotent group, the left-normed commutators $L_n=[\cdots[[x_1,x_2],x_3],\dots x_n]$. In any non-solvable group, the "full binary tree" iterated commutators $T_n=[\cdots[[x_{000},x_{001}],[x_{010},x_{011}]],\cdots]$.

Note that $L_n$ has exponential length in its number $n$ of variables, while $T_n$ has quadratic length in its number $2^n$ of variables.

Question: Is there a solvable group admitting Brunnian words of polynomial length? I.e. for every $n$ a Brunnian word $W_n$ in $n$ letters and polynomial length in $n$?

I'm willing to compromise by allowing constants from the group in $W_n$ (I'm not aware of any example where it helps); and I'm not even aware of a group with subexponential-length Brunnian words.

This is somewhat related to [Elkasapy, Thom: On the length of the shortest non-trivial element in the derived and the lower central series](https://doi.org/10.1515/jgth-2015-0007), but I couldn't make any direct use of their construction.

Comment: @YCor: made edits to reflect the fact that I'm interested in families of words

Comment: What do you think taking a metabelian non-nilpotent group and $W_n=L_{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}$?

Comment: @Ycor: $L_{\log n}$ has a logarithmic number of variables, so definitely we'll want $W_n=L_n$. I see no reason why $L_n$ should be expressible as a shorter word in a metabelian group: $L_n(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)=L_n(x_1,x_2,x_{\sigma(3)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)})$ for any permutation $\sigma$, but that doesn't seem to help in shortening $L_n$.

Comment: Every word in less than $n$ variables has $n$ variables. If you want a reduced word in which all variables appear, consider something akin to $L_{k}(x_1,\dots x_{k})L_{k}(x_{k+1},\dots,x_{2k})\dots$ where $k\sim\log n$.

Comment: @YCor: this will not satisfy the condition $W_n(\dots,1,\dots)=1$ wherever the position of the $1$ is.

Comment: Indeed, that's correct, $n$ is important to emphasize.